# Trying to create a database with the server ID name in Node.JS gives error

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a database with the server ID as the name of the db on the event "guildCreate".
This is my code.

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  console.log(`Joined server: ${guild.name} (ID: ${guild.id}). The server has: ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.size} servers!`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
  console.log("Status: Database created!");
  sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+ guild.id +"";
  con.query(sql1);
});
```

And this is my console output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS2tX.png

EDIT: I did try just now to execute the query without the guild.id variable.

```
sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 154987646546464"; - Works
sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+ guild.id +""; - Does not work.
```

The query with the variable gives me an error, the one without a variable works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: You just need to put tilt keys before and after the guild id.
Ex:

```
sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `"+ guild.id +"`";
```

or

```
sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `479846468464654654`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap that id in single quotes

```
sql1 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '"+ guild.id +"'";
```